# Remove particular category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I am trying to hide "Gyming" category from custom post with custom taxonomy. Tried very hard to get the result but unfortunatly it did'nt work with following code.

```
function cat_subcat(){
$thetax = 'product';
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product',
        //'parent' => 0,
        'hierarchical'=>true,
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'show_count'=>false,
        'show_option_all'=>'',
        'child_of'=>0,
        'depth'=>3,
        'title_li'=>'',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
    );
echo '<ul class="category">';
    wp_list_categories( $args );
echo '</ul>';
```

}

kindly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude a category from the list you have created, you can add `exclude` to your args, where the value is an array of IDs of which categories you want to exclude. So if you wish to exclude the category 'Gyming', you will first have to find the ID of that category. If you're not sure how to find the ID, use the following guide https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tutorial/find-wordpress-category-id/

If the ID is 42, your new code will be

```
function cat_subcat(){
$thetax = 'product';
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product',
        //'parent' => 0,
        'hierarchical'=>true,
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'show_count'=>false,
        'show_option_all'=>'',
        'child_of'=>0,
        'depth'=>3,
        'title_li'=>'',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'exclude'    => array( 42 ),
    );
echo '<ul class="category">';
    wp_list_categories( $args );
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: My category ID is 8, exclude line is added but still its showing 'Gyming' category.